# Need my jQuery tabs not to close when active and already open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am using this jQuery script to hide and reveal 4 div containers with HTML content on the page.

jQuery:

```
$('.content-drawer').hide();
$('#tab1').show();
$('#calc').show();

$('.tab').click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
var target = $(this.rel);
$this.closest('li').addClass('active focus');
// Add the classes to the closest li of the clicked anchor

$('.tab').not($this).closest('li').removeClass('active focus');
// Remove the classes for the non-clicked items

$('.content-drawer').not(target).fadeOut();
// Slideup the other contents

target.delay(400).fadeToggle();
// Toggle the css3-mediaqueriesrrent content

if (target.is(':visible')) {
    // Only if the target is visible remove the active class
    $this.closest('li').removeClass('active');
} 
return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content-drawer" id="tab2">
    <div class="sixcol">
       <img src="css/img/books.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="sixcol last">
      <article>
           <h2>From our family to yours</h2>
           <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem.</p>
           <a class="button fancy" href="#">Learn More</a>
      </article>
   </div>
</div>
```

The client takes issue with it on account of the fact that when you click the div that is currently open, it closes leaving nothing on the screen.

What I Need:
for the open div to not be "closable" on click

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can make sure to have one div visible always is to use the `:visible` [selector that jQuery has](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/). I have modified your code and added this in when you have click a `.tab` tag

```
$('.content-drawer').hide();
$('#tab1').show();
$('#calc').show();

$('.tab').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
    var target = $(this.rel);

    //Get the number of .tabs visible
    var visible = $('.tab').filter(":visible").length;
    //If only one is visible then return before preforming any actions
    if(visible === 1){
        return; 
    }

    $this.closest('li').addClass('active focus');
    // Add the classes to the closest li of the clicked anchor

    $('.tab').not($this).closest('li').removeClass('active focus');
    // Remove the classes for the non-clicked items

    $('.content-drawer').not(target).fadeOut();
    // Slideup the other contents

    target.delay(400).fadeToggle();
    // Toggle the css3-mediaqueriesrrent content

    if (target.is(':visible')) {
        // Only if the target is visible remove the active class
        $this.closest('li').removeClass('active');
    } 
    return false;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Samuel Miller thanks so much for your answer,

but I cant seem to get it to work using that code, I have created a jsfiddle for it here http://jsfiddle.net/jesseatomic/UUB4f/1/

any help would be appreciated

Comment: here is another working version but I need it applied to my code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884880/improve-javascript-jquery-code-for-active-menu-and-show-hide-div?rq=1

my fiddle still found here http://jsfiddle.net/jesseatomic/UUB4f/4/